# Get the 'old' look of Ubuntu on 22.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, 22.04, themes

I am running Ubuntu 22.04LTS, but I love the old look of Ubuntu 14.04, and I really want to customize my Ubuntu to look like [this](https://149366088.v2.pressablecdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ubuntu-desktop.jpg). I can install the Ambience GTK theme and the Humanity icons, but I'd like the same look of the top bar and the dock. Could I maybe get some links to some themes that are similar to this look?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS used the Unity 7 Desktop by default; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS uses the GNOME desktop, but you can easily add the Unity 7 Desktop (*as a second desktop OR replace your GNOME with Unity too*).

Comment: In case you know about Unity, don't want that, but just to customize Gnome, then search the internet for "make gnome look like unity" - [How to Make GNOME Shell Look Like Unity ('Cos Why Not?!) - OMG! Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/01/make-gnome-shell-look-like-unity-desktop), [How to make GNOME Shell look exactly like Unity 7 | Ubunlog](https://ubunlog.com/en/gnome-shell-looks-exactly-like-unity-7/), [How to Make Gnome Shell Look and Feel Like Unity - Make Tech Easier](https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-gnome-look-feel-like-unity/)

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: I know you are on Gnome Ubuntu, but just you might like to know about [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=make+kde+plasma+look+like+unity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install unity7:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

A problem I ran into was when trying to log into unity, it would respond with the error 'Oh no! Something has went wrong!', and only prompted me to log out. To fix this, you need to also install this:

```
sudo apt install dbus-x11
```

It should let you log in after that.